# SQL Server simple Insert statement times out

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, nhibernate, timeout

I have a simple table with 6 columns. Most of the time any insert statements to it works just fine, but once in a while I'm getting a DB Timeout exception:
Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. The statement has been terminated.

Timeout is set to 10 seconds.

I should mention that I'm using NHibernate and that the statement also include a "select SCOPE_IDENTITY()" right after the insert itself.

My thought was that the table was locked or something, but there were no other statements running on that table at that time.

All the inserts are very simple, everything looks normal in sql profiler, the table has no indices but the PK (Page fullness: 98.57 %).

Any ideas on what should I look for?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Our QA had some Excel connections that returned big result sets, those queries got suspended with WaitType of ASYNC_NETWORK_IO for some time. During this time all other queries timed out, so that specific insert had nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 37):

I think your most likely culprit is a blocking lock from another transaction (or maybe from a trigger or something else behind the scenes).

The easiest way to tell is to kick off the `INSERT`, and while it's hung, run `EXEC SP_WHO2` in another window on the same server. This will list all of the current database activity, and has a column called `BLK` that will show you if any processes are currently blocked. Check the `SPID` of your hung connection to see if it has anything in the `BLK` column, and if it does, that's the process that's blocking you.

Even if you don't think there are any other statements running, the only way to know for sure is to list the current transactions using an SP like that one.

Comment: What if the timeout happens occasionally, I can't "catch" the time when it happens to run the debug commands?

Comment: how do you stop the process which is blocking?

Comment: I suppose if your timeout was at 10 seconds you could run the SP_WHO2 (see other answers) after 8 or 9 seconds and see if it caught something. That may be tricky to implement but may be the only way. Of course if it succeeded you'd cancel it before it started.

Answer (score 30):

This question seems like a good place for a code snippet which I used to see the actual SQL text of the blocked and blocking queries.

The snippet below employs the convention that `SP_WHO2` returns "  ." text for `BlockedBy` for the non-blocked queries, and so it filters them out and returns the SQL text of the remaining queries (both "victim" and "culprit" ones):

```
--prepare a table so that we can filter out sp_who2 results
DECLARE @who TABLE(BlockedId INT, 
                   Status VARCHAR(MAX), 
                   LOGIN VARCHAR(MAX), 
                   HostName VARCHAR(MAX), 
                   BlockedById VARCHAR(MAX), 
                   DBName VARCHAR(MAX), 
                   Command VARCHAR(MAX), 
                   CPUTime INT, 
                   DiskIO INT, 
                   LastBatch VARCHAR(MAX), 
                   ProgramName VARCHAR(MAX), 
                   SPID_1 INT, 
                   REQUESTID INT)
INSERT INTO @who EXEC sp_who2

--select the blocked and blocking queries (if any) as SQL text
SELECT 
(
    SELECT TEXT 
    FROM sys.dm_exec_sql_text(
       (SELECT handle 
        FROM (
            SELECT CAST(sql_handle AS VARBINARY(128)) AS handle
            FROM sys.sysprocesses WHERE spid = BlockedId
        ) query)
    )
) AS 'Blocked Query (Victim)',
(
    SELECT TEXT 
    FROM sys.dm_exec_sql_text(
       (SELECT handle 
        FROM (
            SELECT CAST(sql_handle AS VARBINARY(128)) AS handle
            FROM sys.sysprocesses WHERE spid = BlockedById
        ) query)
    )
) AS 'Blocking Query (Culprit)'
FROM @who 
WHERE BlockedById != '  .'
```

Comment: Rats. In SQL 2000, I got incorrect syntax near 'MAX', EXECUTE cannot be used as a source when inserting into a table variable, etc. **What version of SQL does this script require?** It does work on SQL 2008, but that db isn't my problem.

Comment: Did you try using a temporary table instead of a table variable?

Comment: Apologies for the completely useless comment but... Well done that man :) This is a script for the hall of fame. Helped me solve an issue thats been plaguing one of our systems for a long time. +1000

Comment: Wow that's one hell of a query, magic.  A snippet I'll be holding onto forever.

Answer (score 5):

Could be that the table is taking a long time to grow.

If you have the table set to grow by a large amount, and don't have instant file initialization enabled, then the query could certainly timeout every once in a while.

Check this mess out: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175935.aspx)

Comment: autogrowth is set to 1MB, could the allocation of 1MB take so long?

Comment: @meidan no it would not take that long but i would change it to grow in much larger chunks or you'll wind up with a very fragmented file system over time if it is continually growing. the default is 10% and this works well for most except very large dbs.

Comment: @Eam - tanks! its very important on insert large objects

Answer (score 4):

> *no other statements running on that table at that time.*

What about statements running against other tables as part of a transaction? That could leave locks on the problem table.

Also check for log file or datafile growth happening at the time, if you're running SQL2005 it would show in the SQL error logs.

Comment: actually, the transaction inserts into 3 tables, but how could it lock the problem table?

Comment: like this, roughly: 0:begin transaction; 1:update one record in problem table (runs quick); 2:update some other table (takes a long time); 3:commit
problem table will have locks on it until step 3; if another job tries to update a record that is locked, it will wait.

Answer (score 1):

look at fragmentation of the table, you could be getting page splits because of that