# connection timeout error while checking mediastream available or not

Tags: connection-timeout

In My Console application. i am checking  media links which is available in my database through openstream.but one error is raising again and again in diffrent diffrent point.that is "Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. The statement has been terminated"

Answer (score 0):

These 2 similar problems/solutions might give you some ideas. 
One was fragmented table and the other was a lock by another db operation.

http://forums.asp.net/t/1513085.aspx/1/10

[SQL Server simple Insert statement times out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447201/sql-server-simple-insert-statement-times-out)

Comment: Thanks these links help me a lot.