# Can't execute simple query on simple table (timeout)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have the following table design

[image: Table]

When trying to execute the below query, it never completes (Execution time 5 minutes and counting)

```
insert into tableName
(column1, column2, column3)
values ('1000184', '927', '<values>a</values>')
```

Screenshot:
[image: Timeout]

What could be the reason of this? This is a very simple SQL insert query...

Additional information:

- Local Hyper-V machine
- Windows server 2012 R2 (evalutaion period)
- SQL Server 2012

Comment: A lock? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/447201/sql-server-simple-insert-statement-times-out

Comment: I just tried and worked. did you try on different database/sqlserver?

Comment: Will other queries work, or just this one?

Comment: It's just this one. A lot of other queries are working

Comment: It's actually a new table. To avoid the lock problem, can I just remove and re-add the table?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem before. In my situation, there was a trigger getting fired with my insert query and it was blocking SQL Server to complete my insert query. To see that, you should run the insert query and also run the command `EXEC SP_WHO2`, which shows all running processes, in another window in the server. Check the attribute `BLK` there to observe the blocked processes.

Answer (score 0):

Removing and Adding the table again has solved my problem. Probably a lock as Alex K. mentioned

Answer (score -2):

```
INSERT INTO tableName (column1, column2, column3)
VALUES('1000184', '927', '<values>a</values>')
```

Make sure you use correct capitalization when writing a query. Also, check your data types.

For example, `1000184` and `927` do not need to be wrapped with quotations if they are declared as numeric value.

I hope this helps!

Comment: SQL is case **in**-sensitive `insert` is exactly the same thing as `INSERT`